# how do i access these array keys as a variable in CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
Array
(
    [abc] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [title] => hello 12
                    [meta_keyword] => 
                    [meta_description] => 
                    [tags] => sdfgdfg
                    [status] => draft
                    [body] => dsfdsf dfdsafsdfsdfsdf
                    [photo] => images/blog/nari.jpg
                    [raw] => nari
                    [ext] => .jpg
                    [views] => 0
                    [video] => 
                    [categoryid] => 5
                    [subcatid] => 7
                    [featured] => 
                    [pubdate] => 2011-06-17 03:39:55
                    [user_id] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [title] => hello xyz
                    [meta_keyword] => 
                    [meta_description] => 
                    [tags] => xcfasdfcasd
                    [status] => draft
                    [body] => dfdsafsdf dsfdsf dfdsafsdfsdfsdf
                    [photo] => images/blog/nari.jpg
                    [raw] => nari
                    [ext] => .jpg
                    [views] => 0
                    [video] => 
                    [categoryid] => 1
                    [subcatid] => 2
                    [featured] => 
                    [pubdate] => 2011-06-17 03:43:12
                    [user_id] => 0
                )
```

for example if i want to echo out title I would do `echo $abc['title']` but it's not working pls help,

the above output is a result of `print_r($count['abc]);`
it shows nothing when i do `print_r($count['abc']['title'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use the numeric key as well: `$abc[0]['title']`.

In other words, you've got an array with array members of an array type which use numeric keys, in which each of those members are arrays which use associative keys to access values. So you need to access each array in `$abc` to get to the array which contains your `title` values.

**EDIT**

If you're trying to loop through these values, you would need to loop through each array. Such as:

```
$c_abc = count($abc);

for ($i = 0; $i < $c_abc; $i++) {
    echo "{$abc[$i]['title']}<br/>";
}
```

Comment: how do i get this value inside of another foreach loop ?

Comment: @sagarmatha - I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @sagarmatha - Also, if your array is as you suggest in your edit, you would access title with `$count['abc'][0]['title']`.

Answer (score 0):

Read about php associative arrays....you will have you goal achieved

try this:

```
foreach ($array as $i => $values) {
    print "$i {\n";
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        print "    $key => $value\n";
    }
    print "}\n";
}
```

Comment: how do i get that value inside of another foreach loop ?

Answer (score 0):

To access you array variables, the right way is like this

```
$count['abc'][0]['title']
```

---

However, in your title, you are asking about `Array keys as variables?`

Actually this does not need to be related with CI.

A simple example

```
$array = array ( "hi" => "bye");
extract( $array);
//it will make "hi" a variable :: $hi = "bye"

echo $hi; // will output bye
```

Comment: @Jared Farrish, I was not finsished, I have updated my answer, with the solution.

Comment: That is right; the only part about the beginning is that I think it confuses the issue. The OP is certainly struggling, and the first part is not particularly useful. :)

Comment: @Jared Farrish, Alright Jared, I will switch them, but You can't blame me for answering the question in the title too, can you?

Answer (score 0):

Heres structured solution

```
$data = Array(
    [abc] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [title] => hello 12
                    [meta_keyword] => 
                    [meta_description] => 
                    [tags] => sdfgdfg
                    [status] => draft
                    [body] => dsfdsf dfdsafsdfsdfsdf
                    [photo] => images/blog/nari.jpg
                    [raw] => nari
                    [ext] => .jpg
                    [views] => 0
                    [video] => 
                    [categoryid] => 5
                    [subcatid] => 7
                    [featured] => 
                    [pubdate] => 2011-06-17 03:39:55
                    [user_id] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [title] => hello xyz
                    [meta_keyword] => 
                    [meta_description] => 
                    [tags] => xcfasdfcasd
                    [status] => draft
                    [body] => dfdsafsdf dsfdsf dfdsafsdfsdfsdf
                    [photo] => images/blog/nari.jpg
                    [raw] => nari
                    [ext] => .jpg
                    [views] => 0
                    [video] => 
                    [categoryid] => 1
                    [subcatid] => 2
                    [featured] => 
                    [pubdate] => 2011-06-17 03:43:12
                    [user_id] => 0
                )
       )
);

extract($data);

foreach($abc as $value){
    echo $value['title']."<br>";
}
```